# .htaccess protect urls with query string combinations

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I need to protect a "single logical" url in a Joomla CMS with htaccess. I found here [.htaccess code to protect a single URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2670535/htaccess-code-to-protect-a-single-url)

this solution, which works great for a specific url:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/index\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^option=com_content&task=view&id=76$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /secure.htm
```

However, how can I make sure that the url parts can't be swapped around or amended, therefore circumventing the secure access. For example I don't want to allow access to

```
option=com_content&task=view&id=76&dummy=1 
option=com_content&id=76&task=view
```

either.

I have tried this, which doesn't seem to work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/index\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} option=com_content
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} task=view
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=76
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /secure.htm
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your rules work fine for me when I go to any of these URLs:

- `http://localhost/index.php?blah=blah&option=com_content&task=view&id=76`
- `http://localhost/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=76&dummy=1`
- `http://localhost/index.php?option=com_content&id=76&task=view`

I get served the content at `/secure.htm`

However, you could add sound boundaries to your query string rules:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)option=com_content(&|$)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)task=view(&|$)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)id=76(&|$)
```

So that you don't end up matching something like `id=761`